# Correctly creating a list of Tkinter Checkboxes

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a bunch of checkboxes created all under the name `self.ignore` and when I try to write the method call `self.ignore.deselect()` I want all the checkboxes to deselect but nothing happens to any of them. I realize I've probably improperly structured the checkboxes and am looking for a way to fix this. The way I've gone about this is hacky to get to where I am and am looking for a better solution.

I tried just deleting the label that everything is held in. However, when I recreate the label the checkmarks are saved.

Would the correct method of getting my desired result be creating a class called Checkbox and create a class array of each element? What would that look like?

```py
def print_changes(self):
    self.grid_label = Label(root)
    self.grid_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nw")

    for order_num in range(len(self.given_orders)):
        self.ignore = Checkbutton(self.grid_label, variable=self.ignore_list[-1], 
                                  command=lambda position=position - 1: self.ignore_trigger(position - 1), 
                                  onvalue='on', offvalue='off')
        self.ignore.grid(row=position + 1, column=2)

def recalculate(self):
    self.ignore.deselect()
    self.grid_label.destroy()
```

Comment: `self.ignore` is a *single Checkbutton* - whichever one was created last.  Assigning a new value to a variable makes the previous value irrelevant, it doesn't magically turn the variable into a list.  To do something with all of the created Checkbuttons, you'd have to explicitly create a list, and explicitly append each Checkbutton to that list, and iterate over that list to perform some operation on each Checkbutotn.

Comment: `self.grid_label` is widget, but you cannot put  inside `Checkbutton` widget parameter. It should be `root`.